# Does default memory allocated for a datatype play a role in rounding? In what manner a float is rounded if it exceeds allocated memory?

Tags: python-3.x, floating-point, rounding

Having a file test2.py with the following contents:

```
print(2.0000000000000003)    
print(2.0000000000000002)
```

I get this output:

```
$ python3 test2.py  

2.0000000000000004  
2.0
```

I thought lack of memory allocated for float might be causing this but 2.0000000000000003 and 2.0000000000000002 need same amount of memory.

Comment: What do you mean "exceed allocated memory". All floats require the same amount of memory.

Comment: I'm sorry I wasn't clear, I meant what if we take a float which requires more memory then what by default is allocated for it.

i.e, if 4 byte is allocated for a variable having floating point number, what if we store another floating point number which require more then 4 bytes to that variable.

Comment: Floating-pont formats of the type you are using do not use a varying amount of space depending on the value. The number of decimal digits you enter for a number is irrelevant. The format has a fixed number of bits, so it can only represent a fixed number of preset values. When you enter any number, it is converted to the nearest representable value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IEEE 754 64-bit binary floating point always uses 64 bits to store a number. It can exactly represent a finite subset of the **binary** fractions. Looking only at the normal numbers, if `N` is a power of two in its range, it can represent a number of the form, in binary, `1.s*N` where `s` is a string of 52 zeros and ones.

All the 32 bit binary integers, including 2, are exactly representable.

The smallest exactly representable number greater than 2 is 2.000000000000000444089209850062616169452667236328125. It is twice the binary fraction 1.0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001.

2.0000000000000003 is closer to 2.000000000000000444089209850062616169452667236328125 than to 2, so it rounds up and prints as 2.0000000000000004.

2.0000000000000002 is closer to 2.0, so it rounds down to 2.0.

To store numbers between 2.0 and 2.000000000000000444089209850062616169452667236328125 would require a different floating point format likely to take more than 64 bits for each number.

Answer (score 0):

Floats are not stored as integers are, with each bit signaling a yes/no term of 1,2,4,8,16,32,... value that you add up to get the complete number. They are stored as  `sign` + `mantissa` + `exponent` in base 2. Several combinations have special meaning (NaN, +-inf, -0,...). Positive and negative numbers are idential in mantissa and exponent, only the sign differs.

At any given time they have [a specific bit-length](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_754#Basic_and_interchange_formats) they are "put into". They can not overflow.

They have however a minimal accuracy, if you try to fit numbers into them that would need a bigger accuracy you get rounding errors - thats what you see in your example.

More on floats and storage (with example):

- http://stupidpythonideas.blogspot.de/2015/01/ieee-floats-and-python.html
  (which links to a more technical https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html)

More on accuracy of floats:
- [Floating Point Arithmetic: Issues and Limitations](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/floatingpoint.html)